# Find an element in $G$ that has order $20$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have this group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z})^\ast$
And I have to find an element in $G$ that has order $20$.

Can this be done in an easy way?

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried so far?

Comment: Find the "units" i.e. such that $\gcd (n,100) = 1$  And test a few out.  Clearly $1, 99,49$ won't generate $20$ elements.  Nothing that ends in a 1, or a 9 will get the gob done.  And if $49$ generates a group with 2 elements, 7 generates a group with $4$ elements.  That leaves $\{3,13,17\cdots\}$ and many others as candidates.  But guess what.  Each of those 3 will work.

Answer (score 2):

The units group of $\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$ is the product of the units groups of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$. Those two groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$, respectively. If you can find a primitive root modulo $25$, and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem (or more elementary means) to find a residue modulo $100$ congruent to your primitive root mod $25$, and relatively prime to $4$, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The group $G$ has $\varphi(100)=40$ elements, so $a^{40}=1$ for every $a\in G$. Therefore, the order of every element of $G$ divides $40$. Let's try $3$. If we raise $3$ to the divisors of $40$ we obtain:
$$3^2\equiv 9\pmod{100}$$ 
$$3^4\equiv 81\pmod{100}$$
$$3^5\equiv 43\pmod{100}$$
$$3^8\equiv 61\pmod{100}$$
$$3^{10}\equiv 49\pmod{100}$$
$$3^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$$